# What is the VB.net equivalent of VB6's Printer.DrawingMode? (Using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6 namespace)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

In VB6, it's possible to do something like this:

```vb
Printer.DrawMode = vbWhiteness
Printer.Circle (x1, y1), radius1
Printer.DrawMode = vbBlackness
Printer.Circle (x2, y2), radius2
```

The [VB6 compatibility printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb882722(v=vs.140)) for VB.net object does not include `DrawMode` as property.

What would be the equivalent of this in VB.net?

Comment: https://www.vbmigration.com/Resources/detmigratingfromvb6.aspx?Id=19
This article confirms there are a few missing properties from the compatibility version of the `Printer` object.  In this case, is the point of the code to draw a white and a black circle?  If so, the compatibility object does allow you to specify a color:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb918045(v=vs.140)  If you need something more exotic, like xor or merge, it could be harder.